# React Rendering Dynamic Inner Components

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This example illustrates what i`m tryng to do.

The goal is to have a dynamic component array and render it o the screen. I`m not being able to do the rendering part.

```
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import React from 'react';
import MyComponent1 from './MyComponent1.jsx'
import MyComponent2 from './MyComponent2.jsx'

export default class KneatModalContent extends React.Component {

constructor() {
   super();
   this.components = [MyComponent1, MyComponent2];
}

render() {
  return (
  <div className='modal-contents'>
     {this.components.map(function (component, i) {
        return <{ component } key= { i } />
     })}
  </div>
)
}
}
```

I have tryed to create the array as `[<MyComponent1/>, <MyComponent2/>]` as well, as tryed to render as `React.createElement(component, {key:i})` but still couldnt find a solution =(

Comment: What do you expect would happen with `<{ component } />`. You don't render any of your other components like that, you render them as they come, eg: `<MyComponent1 />`. A small nitpick, I wouldn't create the components as an instance property. They could be part of the default properties or the initialState, but not an instance property (it wouldn't be very dynamic if only the instance can mutate them)

Answer (score 3):

In order to create dynamic component, you could just do the following

```
constructor() {
   super();
   this.components = [MyComponent1, MyComponent2];
}



render() {
      return (
      <div className='modal-contents'>
         {this.components.map(function (Component, i) {
            return <Component key= { i } />
         })}
      </div>
    )
  }
```

Comment: Though I have upvoted as it is the correct fix, should one really leave components as instance properties? I think that really negates the dynamic part as the component should now at build time what components it will render (at least from the example). Probably props or state are more appropriate for such templates to occur in

Comment: @Icepickle, I agree, Surely the structuring can be done better to avoid such scenarios

Answer (score 1):

There is a problem in this line:

```
return <{ component } key= { i } />
```

Component is an instance and this is JSX, when you put component in `{}` braces, it means you are taking it as a JavaScript variable. Write this line as:

```
return <Component key={i} />
```