# React call Component dynamically from array of strings

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an array as such:

```
export const options = [
    {id: 1, name='ComponentOne'},
    {id: 2, name='ComponentTwo'},
]
```

Then I have my components:

```
export const ComponentOne = props => (<div>{this.props.content}</div>)
export const ComponentTwo = props => (<div>{this.props.content}</div>)
```

Then I have my view:

```
export class MyView extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {};
    }
    render(){
        return(
            <div>
                {options.map( obj => <obj.name/> )
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

I would like to dynamically render these components but have no idea how to.

Comment: What if you use the component itself instead of the name in `options`? `{id: 1, name=ComponentOne}`. Should it work?

Comment: do you know all the component names that could be in this array? If yes, why not use a switch statement?

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47649723/react-rendering-dynamic-inner-components/47649759#47649759

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of keeping the name of the component class why not keep the class itself. Like so:

```
const options = [
    {id: 1, componentClass: ComponentOne},
    {id: 2, componentClass: ComponentTwo}
];

export class MyView extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {};
    }
    render(){
        return(
            <div>
                {
                  options.map(obj => {
                    const Class = obj.componentClass;

                    return <Class />;
                  })
                }
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: How would I pass the props to `<Class/>`?

Comment: What are the props that you which to pass

Comment: for example the id of MyView Parent Component Okay thanks a lot. This worked.